# AutoCompleteTextView with custom Adapter and filter shows wrong content in soft-keyboard (landscape)

Tags: android, autocomplete, keyboard

Using a modified adapter to show the auto complete list view with different titles, which is working so far. By moving the device into landscape mode the soft keyboard shows upon entering something the suggestion shown on the image. This just runs `.toString()`.
The [implementation](https://gist.github.com/drindt/9946fd74292d1486d64c#file-inventoryitemadapter-java-L344) can be shown here.
I haven't found yet where the text for the keyboard is obtained.
[image: soft-keyboard opened by the auto completion view]